# How to get template field values to Django class based view

Tags: django, class, view

Here is my class, I want to take values to this class from my template 'registeredUsers.html'

```
class registeredusers(RegistrationView, PersonnelView):
    template_name = 'registeredUsers.html'
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context_dict = {}
        context_dict['employeeform']= RegistrationForm  
        empDetails= Employee.object.all() 
        return context_dict
```

Template fields

```
<input class="email" type="email" value="{{i.email}}">
<input class="email" type="email" value="{{i.email}}">
```

Button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

Comment: Maybe sending it via form?

Comment: with out form can you suggest a way and how

Comment: Whats wrong with the form? Or you can inspect the ***`request,POST`***, probably you will get data there